# Angular template driven form: input "component" not binding to form

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I'm trying to generate form fields dynamically based on some JSON object(config). This said config object contains all the attribute values required for constructing form fields(ex: `label`, `type`, `placeholder` etc).

### Setup

In my parent component: I have a form, under which I have an `ngFor`, iterating over the config object, trying to generate the fields.

```
<form #dynamicForm="ngForm">
  <div *ngFor="let field of formFields">    <!-- formFields is the config object -->
    <app-form-field [props]="field" [formData]="formData"></app-form-field>
  </div>
  <button [disabled]="!dynamicForm.form.valid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

To avoid clogging the parent component, I have created a generic `<form-field>` component, which takes all the field attributes(as `props`) and a reference object(to bind the field's value).

```
<div *ngIf="props.type === 'text'">         <!-- One div for each input type -->
  <label [for]="props.id">{{ props.label }}</label>
  <input
    #field="ngModel"
    [id]="props.id"
    [type]="props.type"
    [attr.name]="props.name"
    [placeholder]="props.placeholder"
    [(ngModel)]="formModel[props['apiDataKey']]"
    [required]="props.isRequired"
    [disabled]="props.isDisabled"
  >
</div>

<!-- Other input types here -->
```

### Question

The form tag contains a local reference `#dynamicForm="ngForm"` -> which never seems to update.

While the individual field validations work perfectly fine, the main form(`dynamicForm.value`) seems to:

- contain no data
- as a result of which, the form always shows as valid (`dynamicForm.form.valid` is always `true`)

I've created a demo on stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nvm4hd?file=src/app/app.component.html

PS: I'm pretty new to angular2+, and can't seem to figure out what it is that I'm missing.

Thanks a bunch in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Child Component `viewProviders` array, we can provide `ControlContainer`  to use existing `NgForm` instance:

```ts
@Component({
 ...,
 viewProviders: [ { provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: NgForm } ]
})
export class FormFieldComponent implements OnInit {
 ...
}
```

Comment: This leads to an error "Error: If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name attribute must be set or the form
control must be defined as 'standalone' in ngModelOptions.", see https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zwrvhs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fform-field%2Fform-field.component.ts